# how to save in a json file (for history) the result of a qr code scan in flutter and display the same result in another widget

Tags: flutter, qr-code

please I am new in the development android and moreover flutter. I would like to realize a first project as an autodidact.
the project consists of setting up a flutter application that scans qrcode and displays the result in a new widget. also the user will be able to display the result of the qr code already read (history).

this is the scan file code:

```
class ScanPage extends StatefulWidget {


@override
_ScanPageState createState() => _ScanPageState();
}

class _ScanPageState extends State<ScanPage> {



GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey();
QRViewController controller;
var qrText ="";



@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('app name'),
    /*
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.highlight),
        tooltip: 'Torche',
        onPressed: () {
          Lamp.turnOn();
        },
      ),
    ],*/),

  body:  QRView (key: qrKey,
    overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
      borderRadius: 2,
      borderColor: Colors.green,
      borderLength: 10,
      borderWidth: 5,
      cutOutSize: 300,
    ),
    onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
  ),

  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
    onPressed: () {
      Torch.flash(Duration(seconds: 3));
    },
    label: Text('Torche'),
    icon: Icon(Icons.flash_on),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  ),



 );


}

 @override
 void dispose(){
 controller?.dispose();
 super.dispose();
 }


  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller){
  this.controller = controller;
  controller.scannedDataStream.listen ((scanData){
   setState(() {
     qrText = scanData;
    if (qrText != "") {

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ResultatPage(data: qrText),
        ),
       );

     }
   });
  });
 }
}
```

this now the result widget code

```
class ResultatPage extends StatefulWidget {

  ResultatPage({
    Key key,
    @required data,
    }) : super(key: key);

   final String data="";

    @override
    _ResultatPageState createState() => _ResultatPageState();
      }

   class _ResultatPageState extends State<ResultatPage> {

   String dateHeure = DateFormat('kk:mm - yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now());
   final String data;

   File jsonFile;
   Directory ressources;
   String nomFichier = "historique.json";
   bool fichierExiste = false;
   Map<String, String> fichierContenu;

   @override
   void initState(){
   super.initState();
   getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((Directory directory){
  ressources = directory;
  jsonFile = new File(ressources.path + "/" + nomFichier);
  fichierExiste = jsonFile.existsSync();
  if (fichierExiste) this.setState(() => fichierContenu = 
  json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync()));
  });
  }

  File createFile(Map<String, String> content, Directory dir, String nomFichier){
  File file = new File(dir.path + "/" + nomFichier);
  file.createSync();
  fichierExiste = true;
  file.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(content));
  return file;

 }

  void remplirFichier(String key, String value){
  Map<String, String> content = {key: value};
  if (fichierExiste) {
  Map<String, String> jsonFileContent = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
  jsonFileContent.addAll(content);
  jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(jsonFileContent));

  }  else{
    createFile(content, ressources, nomFichier);
 }
 this.setState(() => fichierContenu = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync()));

 }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('app name'),

  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 170.0,
          width: 300.0,

          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 10.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white70, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0), border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'AUTHENTIFY ME\n',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              Text(
                'Secure Archives',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.red),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              Text(
                '$dateHeure',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19, color: Colors.black),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        Text(
          'Resultet du scan:\n',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
        ),
        Text(
          data,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
            child: Text("OK"),
            onPressed: () => remplirFichier(dateHeure, data)
            )
         ],
       ),
      ),
     );
   }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, any questions? Errors?

Comment: Hello, I can not get the scan result content into the result widget and create a json file to save the user's differend scan

Comment: Do you need camera detect image or make qr code image with result?